# FaceTime Contact Method Priority

Tags: facetime

How does FaceTime determine which contact method to use when FaceTiming with a contact?

For example, if I have one contact on my iPhone. The contact has 2 email addresses, `persona@icloud.com` & `personb@icloud.com`. Each of those email addresses is associated with a different Apple ID & FaceTime account. The only overlap is the contact on my local device. If I tap FaceTime for that contact, which Apple ID will take priority and be called via FaceTime?